# Waydroid in Weston - All Newly Windows Open in Weston, Can Not Multitask (Linux Mint)

Tags: wayland

I am on Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon. Wayland is not there. So, to have an Android emulator, which is Waydroid, we have to first run Weston (=nested Wayland container) and after that we can run Waydroid, which will open in Weston window. This works nicely but...when Weston is running, all newly opened programs will open in Weston (any new program, like terminal, internet browser, password prompt pop-up, whatever). If any program is already opened and we open a second window, it does not open in Weston. This behaviour spoils all the multitasking and moreover, when we accidentally open an internet browser window, it  not only opens in Weston but also deletes all logins. Is there a way to open just Waydroid in Weston without messing with the rest of the system? Or a way to set Weston not to open all windows inside it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run weston with a different socket name.

```
weston --socket=mysocket
```

Source:https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/issues/593#issuecomment-1335805761

Comment: `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` env variable must be exported for waydroid session to start: `export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=weston-socket-waydroid; weston --socket=$WAYLAND_DISPLAY &; waydroid session start &`